# How to find a key in a JSON file with Gson library?

Tags: java, json, gson

Given a JSON file which looks like the code below, how can I find a specific key with its corresponding value without hard-coding the structure in a Java class or otherwise. Let's say I want to get "Signal_Settings" as a JSON Object but given the possibility of changes in the JSON file structure I want to get this object regardless for example by iterating through all keys in the file. I have tried to do this iteratively and failed, so I think a recursive function is the way for which I didn't find a solution yet. My iterative code looks like this:

```
while (true) {
            try {
                for(Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry:newJsonObj.entrySet()){
                    System.out.println(entry.getKey());
                    System.out.println("Before NewJsonObj:" + newJsonObj);
                    newJsonObj = newJsonObj.getAsJsonObject(entry.getKey());
                    System.out.println("After NewJsonObj:" + newJsonObj + "\n");

                    //tempEntrySet = newJsonObj.entrySet().iterator().next();
                }

                //System.out.println("Key:" + tempEntrySet.getKey());

                //System.out.println("TempEntry:" + tempEntrySet);
            }catch (Exception e){
                break;
            }
        }
```

and the JSON file:

```
{
    "config2": {
        "UDP_Settings": {
            "ListenAddress": "'127.0.0.1'",
            "ListenPort": "54523"
        },
        "Signal_Settings": {
            "Count": 1,
            "Signals": [
                {
                    "Name": "time",
                    "Type": "uint8",
                    "Interval": "foo",
                    "Description": "",
                    "Unit": null
                },
                {
                    "Name": "othersignal",
                    "Type": "uint8",
                    "Interval": "fff",
                    "Description": "",
                    "Unit": null
                }
            ]
        },
        "Tag_Settings": null,
        "Model_Settings": null
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `newJsonObj.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("config2").getAsJsonObject("Signal_Settings")` what you're looking for?

Comment: If you know what the key is, you don't need to cycle through the keys.

Comment: I dont want to hard-code the structure. I want to get to the tag without knowing the underlying structure to get to it.